# VBA - Create new sheet and rename it

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am trying to insert a new sheet and then rename it to the current month and year just with one button. For some extra information: I'm planning on removing this button a bit later on so that it will be automatic.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  nowMonth = Month(Now)
  nowYear = Year(Now)

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)Name = "nowMonth & , & nowYear)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to replace `"nowMonth & , & nowYear)` with `nowMonth & "," & nowYear`

Comment: I just tried it and still got Syntax error

Comment: why did you not mention syntax error in your question?

Comment: you are missing a dot `.` before `Name`  .... Name is a property of the Worksheet object  .... so the syntax is `worksheets(2).Name`

Comment: you also have an extra bracket after `nowYear`   ... and a leading quote `"` , but no closing quote ..... if you do not need a comma in sheet name, then you can use `nowMonth & nowYear`  .... or `month(now) & year(now)`

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
nowMonth = Month(Now)
nowYear = Year(Now)

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = nowMonth & "," & nowYear
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider to have some kind of error handling to check if the sheet you are adding already exists otherwise if somehow you run the same code again, it will give you an error and a new default sheet will also be added at the same time which I don't think what you would want.

Also it's a good practice to declare all the variables used in the code.

You should try it like this...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nowMonth As Integer, nowYear As Integer
nowMonth = Month(Now)
nowYear = Year(Now)
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = wb.Sheets(nowMonth & ", " & nowYear)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not ws Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The Sheet called " & nowMonth & ", " & nowYear & " already exists in the workbook.", vbExclamation, "Sheet Already Exists!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = nowMonth & ", " & nowYear
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
Private Sub sheet()   
    nowMonth = Month(Now)
    nowYear = Year(Now)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = nowMonth & "," & nowYear
End Sub
```